# Publishing a library that requires CSS with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, datatables, amd

I publish a library called [DataTables](//datatables.net) and I'm looking to improve how it works with package managers for the next set of releases. RequireJS is the one i'm specifically looking at just now. Building the Javascript AMD support for RequireJS in DataTables is relatively simple, however, DataTables doesn't really make a lot of sense without some styling.

I publish a number of styling integrations (Bootstrap, Foundation, jQuery UI and DataTables own default with others planned) so I'd like to have something like `require(['jquery', 'datatables.net-bs'], ... );` which will include DataTables and the Bootstrap styling for DataTables.

I could simply list a bunch of `<link>` tags for folks to include, but if I do that, I might as well just publish the `<script>` tags and forego RequireJS altogether.

I know that [CSS is not supported](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css) by the RequireJS core, but I was hoping to use the [require-css](https://github.com/guybedford/require-css) plug-in. That works well, but I can't find a way to have a module name include both the JS and CSS.

I found that the `config.paths` option for a module could specify multiple files in an array, so I tried:

```
'datatables.net-bs': [
    'require-css!//nightly.datatables.net/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min',
    '//nightly.datatables.net/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min',
]
```

But the plug-ins operate on the module name, not the path. I had a look at the plug-ins API but can't see an option to add a plug-in at that point (unless anyone knows better)?

If that isn't the best approach, can anyone suggest what is a better one?

This is what I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/coaqsjkv/  - note that the CSS "plug-in" is not resolved at the path level giving a 404.

I could have the `require` list all the JS files and CSS files needed - but that seems very verbose (three files for DataTables with Bootstrap styling for example).

Any insights very welcome.